# Is there a way to set a Github workflow/action to update a draft release's tag, name and target?

Tags: github-actions

I'm currently using the [Release Drafter](https://github.com/release-drafter/release-drafter) workflow that creates a draft release whenever a PR is merged into the `develop` branch (staging). This creates a great draft but now I'm wanting to have it get published when develop is merged into master.  When that takes place I need to update the release name and tag before publishing. Then send out a notification in our slack engineering channel.

**What I can do:**

- Setup the action on push into master.
- Get the [latest draft release](http://InsonusK/get-latest-release) and then use that id as a ref.
- Publish using [eregon/publish-release](https://github.com/elgohr/Github-Release-Action) action.
- Send the slack message

**What I missing:**

- An Action that I can pass the release id and update the tag and name.

The name and tag will be the current date `%Y.%m%.d-%H:%M`

Here is the action YML I have created so far

```
name: On master merged publish release & notify
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "master"
jobs:
  release:
    name: Publish GitHub Release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Create tag from date
      id: create_tag
      run: |
        tag=builds-$(date +%Y.%m%.d__%H:%M)
        echo "::set-output name=tag::$tag" #  https://github.com/ruby/ruby-dev-builder/blob/master/.github/workflows/build.yml
    - name: Get last Draft
      id: last_release
      uses: InsonusK/get-latest-release@v1.0.1 # https://github.com/InsonusK/get-latest-release
      with:
        myToken: ${{ github.token }} # TODO check if set
        exclude_types: "release"
        view_top: 1
    - name: "Print result"
        run: |
          echo "id: ${{ steps.last_release.outputs.id }}"
          echo "name: ${{ steps.last_release.outputs.name }}"
          echo "tag_name: ${{ steps.last_release.outputs.tag_name }}"
          echo "created_at: ${{ steps.last_release.outputs.created_atd }}"
          echo "draft: ${{ steps.last_release.outputs.draft }}"
          echo "prerelease: ${{ steps.last_release.outputs.prerelease }}"

    # This is Pseudocode.
    - name: update release
      id: update_release
      uses: tubone24/update_release@v1.0
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
      with:
        tag:  ${{ steps.create_tag.outputs.tag }}

    - name: Publish Release
    - uses: eregon/publish-release@v1 #https://github.com/elgohr/Github-Release-Action
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      with:
        release_id: ${{ steps.last_release.outputs.release_id }}
    # Needs test
    - name: Slack Notification Success
      uses: rtCamp/action-slack-notify@v2
      env:
        SLACK_CHANNEL: automated-deploys
        SLACK_COLOR: green
        SLACK_MESSAGE: ${{ steps.last_release.outputs.body }} # TODO get info
        SLACK_TITLE: Deploying 
        SLACK_USERNAME: GH Action Parrot
        SLACK_ICON: https://emoji.slack-edge.com/T3LPQHAMV/headbangingparrot/1898efdc354c8ff8.gif
        SLACK_WEBHOOK: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a step that updates the release draft using Github's REST API:

```
- name: Update draft to ${{ github.event.client_payload.release_tag }}
    run: |
      curl \
        -u user:${{ secrets.USER_TOKEN }} \
        -X PATCH \
        -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
        https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repository}/releases/${{ steps.last_release.outputs.release_id }} \
        -d '{"tag_name":"${{ steps.last_release.outputs.tag_name }}", "name": "${{ steps.last_release.outputs.tag_name }}", "draft": "false"}'
```